# is a .code-workspace file preferred over a vscode/ folder when working in a monorepo and using vscode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, monorepo, organization, npm-workspaces

my team is working in a monorepo with multi-level packages. we are trying to decide between the two, but the entire project and its packages are written in typescript and have a shared eslint configuration, so code styling and stuff is intended to be the same across those packages. I was personally leaning towards a `.code-workspace` but some team members thought a `.vscode/` folder made sense as well. I didn't have a strong opinion but wanted to know if people have a valid reasoning behind choosing one over the other given our use case?

structure

```
root/
  - packages/
    - foo/
    - bar/
    - baz/
    - .../
```

## intention

the intention for such a configuration file to exist is to commit it to source control and streamline editor configuration for the team members working on this project.